# Better solution to SqlDataSource?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, datasource

I need to display some data from a view in a SQL Server database on several pages of my website. I've done it by using `SqlDataSource` within my `web.config` and then used a `GridView` control within my `.aspx` page to display the data.

Now, this works but I read in some forum that it is bad practice to do use `SqlDataSource`? I will probably need to have the ability for the admin/user to filter the data in the future, so I'm not sure how this would work with my current implementation.

My code so far looks like this :

In the `web.config` file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test1.ConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=...."
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

And something like this in my aspx

```
<body id="wrap" >
  <form  runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" 
         BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
         DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="500px" Width="408px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Title">
                <ItemStyle Width="400px" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="100px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Result" HeaderText="Result" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Result" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="100px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#002756" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003466" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#002756" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#002756" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings: Test1.ConnectionString %>" 
         SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Test1.ConnectionString]"> 
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
  </form>
</body>
```

So my question is is there a better way to implement this, keeping in mind that I will probably need a function for the user/admin to filter the data by certain criteria?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using code behind to fetch the data?

Comment: I come from a php background and quite new to asp.net so still trying to get my head around this. But I guess that would be the better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment I would recommend you use the code behind to achieve this as it's much easier to make changes if required in the future. I'm assuming you've got a table in your database named `Test1`. We'll first create a class to represent this in C# and add a few properties which we'll use later on.

```
public class Test
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public int Result { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's create a method which returns a collection of values from your database.

```
public List<Test> GetData()
{
    List<Test> myList = new List<Test>();

    string sqlQuery = "Select Title, Result From Test";
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test1.ConnectionString"].ConnectionString; //Read connection string from config file

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con))
        {
            //Add param here if required.
            con.Open(); //Open connection
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Test t = new Test();
                    t.Title = reader["Title"].ToString();
                    t.Result = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Result"]);

                    myList.Add(t);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return myList;
}
```

Finally, you want to set the datasource for the GridView. I'm going to assume you have a page called `MyGridPage.aspx` open up the `MyGridPage.asps.cs` and in your `Page_Load` event you can set the `DataSource` for your grid as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        GridView1.DataSource = t.GetData();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

If you wanted to filter your `Sql` query by for example username you'll change it as:

```
string sqlQuery = "Select Title, Result From Test Where username = @username";
```

Then you can pass in the `@username` parameter as:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = myUsername;
```

`myUsername` can be of someone who's logged into your app. You will pass the parameter(s) before you open the connection. Passing parameters will also prevent sql injection which I suggest you read up on in case you're not aware.

Note: it is recomenned to make use of `using` block to ensure the connection object is closed and disposed correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a go.

Comment: Just a quick question- I am now getting this error: CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct   for the public LIst<Test> GetData() line. Any idea why I get this error?

Comment: The method needs to be inside of a class not outside i.e. inside of `public class Test { //Method here } //Not here`

Comment: Thanks. the issue I've got now is that it throws up an error saying that the name 'GridView1' does not exist in the current context?

Comment: Check your markup code and see if your `<asp:GridView />` is named `GridView1`

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessarily bad practice to use SqlDataSource... but it does tend to mingle your data access code with your presentation code. Additionally, you can often do better with an [`ObjectDataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx.aspx) that wraps your view. There's a little more code involved (you'll have to create a new class somewhere to select from your view), but you end up with methods that can be easily updated or replaced in the future to handle whatever changes you may need.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically set the data source of the grid view.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArts e)
    {
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM Test"; //your SQL query goes here
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(table);

            GridView1.DataSource = table;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            cmd.Dispose();
            da.Dispose();
        }
    }
```